# HTML file that opens a link in a browser

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink

Is there a way for an HTML file or other format that when clicked, will open the default browser and navigate to a specified `http://` web page, NOT a local `file://` ?

Comment: So if I have a HTML file on my desktop and click it, you want it to open a browser and go to a certain URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script>
  location.href = 'www.someUrl.com'
</script>
```

Just create an html file that contains something like the above. When you click it you will be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a shortcut.
Create shotcut and type your browser application url and add link.
Example like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for an HTML file, no. When you click on an HTML file, your computer will open it in your default web browser, and the URL at the top will will be a `file://` as that's the location of your file. You can, however, include some JavaScript to redirect people.

```
<script>window.location = "https://www.google.com";</script>
```

That way people will open the local file, but they will be automatically redirected to Google.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a discernible difference between `location.href` and `window.location`.  Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if there is a way to set your HTML files to a default web browser, so that when you double-click them, they'll open up in....lets say for example (chrome.exe, firefox, opera, etc etc...)? If so, I recommend you right click the HTML file and navigate to "open with", and choose the web browsing program you want to use.

If you really want to take the easy route. Download notepand++ text editor(notepad-plus-plus.org).

Here's a picture of how to run HTML file in notepad++ in the browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuynt.png